# Ui path error while writing cell activity

Tags: uipath, uipath-activity

Expression Activity type 'VisualBasicValue`1' requires compilation in order to run.  Please ensure that the workflow has been compiled.

how to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when a string with quotes is copied from a RTF formatted app, such as Microsoft Word. The " quotation character is not the code version. Try deleting the current assignment in the write cell activity and type manually so that the quotes (") are of the right type. Notice the slanted quotes vs. the straight quotes in the two examples below:

“This is a quote from an RTF app”

"This is a quote from a code editor"

Answer (score 0):

Is this regarding reading PDF with OCR?  If so, or possibly even if not:

Try creating a wrapper workflow around the activity, without any other activities in the workflow.  Pass input and output through the workflow arguments.

Good luck.

https://forum.uipath.com/t/any-reason-for-which-ocr-activities-dont-work-in-a-c-project/495055/15